# I want the letters to be as tall/big as my `TextInput` height

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using RN 50. I have a `TextInput` with a `height` of 40. But the text doesn't get as big as my textInput. I tried `allowFontScaling={true}` but didn't work. So I want the letters to be as tall/big as my `TextInput` height.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass a `fontSize` along with the `height`:

```
<TextInput style={{ height: 40, fontSize: 40 }} />
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried wrapping it all in text and applying the font size to the outer text?

```
<Text style={{fontSize: xx})>
<TextInput/>
<Text/>
```

Alternatively you have tried this?

```
<TextInput 

      style={{fontSize: 40}}
    />
```